# 'Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Guid and System.String.'

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, guid, bindingsource

I'm trying to query a BindingSource with multiple Foreign Key values. The Foreign Keys are GUIDs and when I apply a filter like

"product = '1c0f4868-5d96-4653-a7f7-d83eab5ecaa6'"

it works fine, however I'm attempting to apply

"product in ('4f7f57b0-23f6-4c7c-994d-07bf84586857', 'b037071b-a597-48af-8f83-1a585edc841e')".

When this line is hit it throws the title error.

Comment: Try `product in (Guid.parse("4f7f57b0-23f6-4c7c-994d-07bf84586857"), Guid.parse("b037071b-a597-48af-8f83-1a585edc841e"))` for example

Comment: This did not work, I got the same error.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [mcve]. After that try improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution, when using IN the GUID values must be converted to GUID by your sever, so the filter must be

"product in (CONVERT('4f7f57b0-23f6-4c7c-994d-07bf84586857', 'System.Guid'), CONVERT('b037071b-a597-48af-8f83-1a585edc841e', 'System.Guid'))";